# ActiveRecord is treating attribute as Integer when it's Decimal in MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I feel like I'm taking crazy pills here. I have a MySQL-backed ActiveRecord class and a number of the attributes are reported in Rails as type Integer:

```
Device.last.score.class # returns `Fixnum`
```

MySQL reports the column being of type `decimal(10,0)`.

What am I missing here? Even tried a call to `reset_column_information`. Migration looks correct and schema file looks OK too.

Note: this issue wasn't happening in dev, where I'm using SQLite.

Here is my migration:

```
class AddScoreColumnToDevices < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change  
        add_column :devices, :score, :decimal
    end
end
```

Comment: Assuming you have some records in there , what does `Device.first.score.class` report? (instead of `Device.new`)

Comment: `Fixnum` as well. I was incorrect above, `Device.new.score.class` actually returns `NilClass` for obvious reasons. Fixing that now.

Comment: Can you save a new Device with a float/decimal score? `Device.create(score: 11.11)`?

Comment: Also, I would suggest posting your Device model code and the migration you used to create the Device table/score column. Such will help answering your question more quickly...

Comment: @CarlosDrew New records have the same issue. I posted the migration above; it's extremely vanilla. I did not include the class definition because I don't even make mention of the `:score` attribute in it. It's a basic model class that inherits directly from `ActiveRecord::Base`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The migration did it for me! Thank you!

The defaults for a newly migrated `:decimal` are `:precision => 0` and `:scale => 0`, which will result in a MySQL decimal accepting nothing after the decimal point.

Ruby will see that number, with nothing after the decimal point, as a Fixnum, which is what you are observing.

So, you need to write a new migration to alter the column and give the decimal precision and scale > 0.

```
change_column :devices, :score, :decimal, :precision => 10, :scale => 10
```

References:
[ActiveRecord ConnectionAdapter TableDefinition #column](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column)
[decimal precision and scale](http://ariejan.net/2012/08/28/rails-migrations-decimal-precision-and-scale/)
[old reference on MySQL column<->Ruby datatype mapping](http://www.orthogonalthought.com/blog/index.php/2007/06/mysql-and-ruby-on-rails-datatypes/)